# What is abstraction of direction in considering vectors such as used in Engineering & Physics?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces

In the use of vectors of engineering and physics, we encounter objects that obey the axioms of a vector space but also have two new attributes of length (or, magnitude) and direction (e.g. direction in space).

In the study of vector spaces, you do not encounter these notions of length and direction.  To obtain the idea of length, you need to consider a vector space with added structure to include the concept of normed vector elements as commonly displayed in Banach Space or Hilbert space (or others).  Indeed, other attributes such as a metric (e.g. Banach), and inner product can be included.

But, where does the notion of *direction* come in?  The closest I get is the idea of using direction cosines derived from the inner product of an N-dimensional space of vectors.  But, is this the only abstraction of direction (which is not much of an abstraction to me).

I am not sure what I am looking for but I guess maybe if someone could name a formal algebraic structure (extension of Banach Space?) where direction is included as one of the added structures and then I could use that to study.

Comment: At least in my experience with applications of linear algebra, I find that I use inner products *everywhere* and sometimes use [exterior products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra). There's not much more useful structure I seem to come across.

Comment: The direction of a vector is just the one-dimensional subspace that it generates.

Comment: Other than Jack M's answer, we can only describe direction with respect to some pre-selected reference vectors, most naturally a basis, and then an inner product is what you need to compute the angles with the basis vectors.

Answer (score 2):

Well we already seem to have a structure that encompasses length and direction in the notions of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Describe a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $(r,\theta)$ where $r$ is the *length* of the vector and $\theta$ is the *direction* of the vector.

In $\mathbb{R}^n$ we can do the exact same thing, just using the $n$-tuple

$$(r,\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_{n-1})$$ so that the $\theta_i$'s give all necessary information about direction.

Indeed it is not necessary for a general 'weird' vector space to have a well-defined notion of direction, as is the case of $C^{\infty}_c(X)$, all infinitely differentiable functions of compact support over a topological space $X$.

The tangent space of a smooth manifold $M$, denoted $TM$ is an example of an affine space in which there is a notion of 'direction', relative to each point $x \in M$.

Perhaps define direction as being invariant under simple translations? For example, if I move a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ without rotation, surely I preserve direction. Maybe even go as far as to say that $e^x$ and $e^x+c$ surely have the 'same direction' in $C^{\infty}(X)$.

Therefore it *may* make sense to define length as that which is invariant under rotation and translation but **not** scaling, while direction is that which is invariant under translation and scaling but **not** rotation.

Comment: But, such definitions assume the idea of an origin and orientation which are commonly associated with a coordinate system or coordinate frame.  I am hoping to find some definition that does not use a coordinate frame or I am guessing that hopefully such a definition exists.

Comment: @K7PEH It would seem that direction would be impossible to define properly in a co-ordinateless system, as this begs the question: "direction relative to **what**?"

Comment: @K7PEH And further, if you have a vector space, you have an origin. If you don't have an origin, you're talking about affine space.

Comment: @K7PEH  You could look at the notion of the tangent space to a manifold, which is an affine space with 'direction'

Comment: "direction relative to what" is precisely the issue that lead me to this question.  I was thinking about the arbitrariness of the notion of direction when I was thinking about coordinate frame rotations and other coordinate transformations.  The idea of direction as some "idea" loses meaning without some other reference direction and therefore I started wondering what kind of algebraic (or even topological) structure defines this kind of thing.  Thus, the motivation of my question.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter -- I am still reading and renewing lost knowledge about manifolds and tangent spaces.  The idea of "direction" defined for each point $x \in{M}$ requires some kind of directional derivative (I think) to single out a unique direction ($\partial_{\mu}$).

Comment: @K7PEH It would seem that *something* is always needed to single out direction in a space. Angle, in $\mathbb{R}^n$, directional derivative in an affine tangent space, whatever you want to call 'direction' in $C^k(X)$, etc

Comment: Yes, direction may always assume some kind of reference.  Is there such an idea of a parallel line if you have no other lines to determine whether your line is indeed parallel?  That is, two lines are parallel if they do not intersect (or, alternatively, only intersect at infinity).  And, likewise, a directed line segment (a direction) is just as meaningless without a reference as a single parallel line.  Maybe this is the best answer!

Answer (score 1):

Relative directions of elements of vector spaces can be expressed via the scalar product: If we have a (pre-)Hilbert space $\cal H$ with a scalar product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$, then we say that two elements $f,g \in \cal H$ are orthogonal (i.e. their relative angle is 90°) if $\langle f, g \rangle = 0$.

If you take a (say, finite) set of vectors in $\cal H$, you can find a set of vectors which have the same span $\cal M$ as your original set, but its elements are piecwise orthogonal. You can do this with the Gram-Schmidt process, ending up with an orthogonal basis of $\cal M$. Thus, a scalar product helps you to 'establish' something like a coordinate system.

Furthermore, if you are not interested in finite-dimensional subsets, but the whole space, then you can start to look at complete orthonormal systems (sets of vectors which have norm equal to 1, are pairwise orthonormal and whose span is the whole Hilbert space).

Now to get back to the original geometric interpretation. If you have a scalar product and a complete orthonormal system $\{e_1, e_2, \dots\}$ of a Hilbert space (i.e. a coordinate system), then you can take a vector $f\in H$ and define

$$\arccos \left(\frac{\langle f,e_i\rangle}{\langle f,f \rangle^{1/2}}\right)$$

to be the angle between the 'direction' of $e_i$ and $f$. If the angle is 0°, then you can look at the term inside the $\arccos$ to see if they point in the same direction (it has the value +1) or in the opposite direction (it has thevalue -1).

Comment: Before I posted my question, I thought of inner products and direction cosines with a basis as the means of defining direction.  But, this seemed so loose to me that I thought that there had to be something better and maybe I was looking for something more abstract in a topological sense (I always think of topology as abstract because it confuses me).  Yet, maybe there isn't anything more abstract.  Maybe this is all there is.  Indeed, maybe the idea of direction should be dropped from the vocabulary of vectors (with an inner-product) and only think in terms of inner-product itself.

Comment: @K7PEH exactly why I stayed away from this in my answer

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion *direction* can be defined only fo Hilbert spaces ( sice these are the spaces where we cand define an *angle*).

If $V$ is an Hilbert space than, given two vectors $v,w$ we can say that they have the same direction ad are equi-oriented iff $ \langle v,w\rangle=||v||\cdot||w||$ and have the same direction but are opposite iff $ \langle v,w\rangle=-||v||\cdot||w||$.

This seems a good definition that works also for infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces.